# Can not login to FB using FB connect in IPhone app since morning

Tags: facebook, fbconnect

I am not able to login to Facebook through my application in iphone since morning. It was working perfectly fine at night.
Also its  not showing the same login dialog box.

It would be great if someone tell me whats the problem.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was because FB made some changes in the SDK that time.